# Where can I find a Linux implementation of cksum that does what OSX cksum -o3 does?

Tags: linux, macos, checksum, gnu-coreutils

I am trying to reproduce the CRC32 calculations that the u-boot crc32 command does with a Linux utility.

I have discovered, by experiment, that OSX cksum command, with the -o3 option will produce identical check sums to those produced by u-boot crc32 command, but that the GNU coreutils version of cksum does not support the -o3 option and does not produce the same results as u-boot crc32. I have also tried the GNU coreutils 'sum' command.

Does anyone know of a debian package that has a cksum command (or equivalent) that produces the same outputs as the cksum -o3 command on OSX?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the `cksum` command?

Comment: I am generating a u-boot script for flashing partitions of a NAND flash memory. The u-boot build I am using has a crc32 facility. I want my script to check that source materials and resulting flash have the expected crc. To do this, I need the system which is generating the u-boot script to be able perform the same calculation.

Comment: I see. I know that CRC32 is a kind of standard for embedded devices. Still I suggest to consider using a more modern algorithm like SHA-2 which is standardized and much better at detecting corrupted data than CRC32.

Comment: Agreed. It is something I might do longer term, but for now, I just need the crc32 implementation. Before I received Alper's answer, I ended up wrapping the u-boot function with something than mmap'd the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cksum` from package `coreutils` doesn't support `-o3` option, however, there is another `cksum` from `freebsd-buildutils` with `-o3` support.

```
$ sudo apt-get install freebsd-buildutils
```

After installation of `freebsd-buildutils`, be sure that you run the correct `cksum`.

```
$ dpkg-query -L freebsd-buildutils
```

gives the file list installed with `freebsd-buildutils`, for example in my environment it is in `/usr/lib/freebsd/cksum`

Answer (score 0):

There is also a `crc32` command that is installed by `apt-get install libarchive-zip-perl` in Debian:

```
$ printf %i\\n 0x$(crc32 <(printf aa))
126491095
$ crc32 <(printf aa)
078a19d7
```

In OS X `cksum -o3` also prints the length in a second column though:

```
$ printf aa|cksum -o3
126491095 2
```